# How is $P=4P−3RP$ equal to $1=4−3R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How is $P=4P−3RP$ equal to $1=4−3R$ when by dividing both sides by $P$ one eliminates two $P's$ at the right side of the equation while having only one $P$ in the denominator.

Comment: What *denominator*? And the claim is true **only if** $\;P\neq0\;$ , whatever those letters stand for.

Comment: $4P - 3RP = P(4 - 3R)$, and so $(4P - 3RP)/P = (P/P)(4 - 3R) = 4 - 3R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing both sides of the equation by $P\require{cancel}$, under the provision $P\neq 0$: $$\frac PP = \frac{ 4P - 3RP}P \iff 1\overset{\color{red}{\Large *}}= \frac{(4-3R)P}P = \frac{(4-3R)\cancel{P}}{\cancel{P}} = {4-3R}$$

$\color{red} {\large *}$ This equivalence follows from the distributive property of multiplication over addition.

Comment: Please include that the regrouping of the numerator follows the rule of distributive property of multiplication to avoid possible confusion of others in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By the distributive property of multiplication with respect to addition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) one has

$$
4P−3RP = (4-3R)P
$$

so now it's evident that you can divide both sides of

$$
P=(4-3R)P
$$

by $P$ and obtain the solution.

Comment: This answer completely answers my question, thanks.